# Restrict Function Calls in Child Class

Tags: java, function, inheritance, function-calls

I have a base class Base, and  derived classes from it such as DerivedA, DerivedB etc. And I have task classes derived from android.os.AsyncTask such as TaskA, Task B, TaskC etc.

What I want to accomplish is restricting calls in Task classes to specific Derived classes. Such as

TaskA can call functions from DerivedA, but not from DerivedB,DerivedC etc ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every class can call `public` methods. You could restrict access by putting your classes in separate packages and use package-private access. See [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) if you don't know it already.